# Assigning StackElements without multiple for loops in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have 30 chocolates in a stack and I want to distribute it to 3 people

```
public class People
{
  public int Id{get;set;
  public Stack<Chocolate> chocolates{get;set;}
}


Stack<Chocolate> chocolateObjects;
    List<People> peopleList;
```

How can we assign to three people in this example in the same for loop?
The first person should get first ten chocolates,
second person should get choclates from 11-20 and so on.
I have tried doing is:

```
People p = new People ();


foreach(var a in chocolateObjects)
{
  Chocolate c= a.pop();
 p.Chocolates.push(c);  
}
```

The number of people and chocolates are also generic

Comment: Why do you want to complete this task in one loop?

Comment: You don't need any loops, you could do: `peopleList[0].chocolates = new Stack<Chocolate>(chocolateObjects.Take(10))` and then `peopleList[1].chocolates = new Stack<Chocolate>(chocolateObjects.Skip(10).Take(10))` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to loop through each person, and give them upto 10 chocolates each

```
        Stack<Chocolate> chocolateObjects = new Stack<Chocolate>();
        List<People> peopleList = new List<People>()
        {
            new People(),
            new People(),
            new People(),
        };

        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());
        chocolateObjects.Push(new Chocolate());

        foreach (var p in peopleList)
        {
            while (p.chocolates.Count < 10 && chocolateObjects.Count>0)
            {
                var a = chocolateObjects.Pop();
                p.chocolates.Push(a);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(p.chocolates.Count());
        }
```